# IMF SDR Rate api

Tags: api

i am trying to find an api to get sdr to euro rate. the regular web page is as follows: 
https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx

Does anyone can recommend me a api service either paid or free?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just fetch the web page and parse it to get the info? Which programming language?

Comment: Fetching and parsing would work but i prefer api for its simplicity and reliability. If they change the design of the website i would have to change my code again. At the end that will be my last option. I don't know if programming language option makes a difference for my question